# elasticsearch query for fields that contain multiple unique values

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field that has values in it like this:

```
sourceTypes: ["book", cartoon"]
```

**How can I query for items where sourceTypes are both?**

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "script": {
              "script": "doc['sourceTypes'].values[0] = \"cartoon\""
            }
          },
          {
            "script": {
              "script": "doc['sourceTypes'].values[1] = \"book\""
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the above query, I get this:
Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: UnsupportedOperationException[modifying list opertations are not implemented]; }]

and with this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "feeds.sourceTypes": "[\"cartoon\", \"book\"]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I get no errors but return null.

**UPDATE: I found that this works for me.**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "sourceTypes": "cartoon book"
    }
  }
}
```

**Is there a more performant way to do it?**

Updating to add mappings:

```
"sourceTypes": {
    "type": "string"
}
```

and a partial document:

```
sourceTypes: [
    "book",
    "cartoon"
]
```

What I really want to do is get all the documents where sourceTypes aren't the same.  So if it's book and magazine, I want it.  If it's book, book, I don't want it.

Thanks!

Comment: can you share the mapping for the field sourceTypes and a couple of sample documents?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, you have an array field **sourceTypes** that you want to query. You can use **term query** for that provided the field is **not_analyzed**. A sample query can look like this:

```
  "query" : { 
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {
          "term" : {"sourceTypes" : "book"}
        }, 
        { 
          "term" :{"sourceTypes" : "cartoon"}
        }
      ], 
      "must_not" : [], 
      "should" :   []
    }
  }
```

The above query will make sure that only those documents are returned where **sourceTypes** field contain both **book** and **cartoon**. 
I hope it solves your problem. If not. please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks.  What is the difference between the way you did it here and the way I did it in my update?

Comment: Also is there a way for me to get this into a filter?

Comment: You are using a match_phrase query in your update which is pretty expensive...Using terms query is faster since it works on terms level. Yes, you can get this in filter simply remove query in the above post with filter. It'll work as bool filter. Thanks

Comment: Ok that works for this small subset of data.  Now do you know how get documents where the two values in the sourceTypes field aren't the same, without hardcoding 'book' or 'cartoon'?  thx.

Comment: Which two values in sourceTypes not same ? Can you explain a bit more, I'm not getting the question properly.

Comment: I want to say where sourceType[0] <> sourceType[0], not knowing what the source types are (there are way more than just cartoon and book).  I'm pretty sure I have to redo the data model and have separate fields so that I can say doc1.sourceType <> doc2.sourceType